# Cannot reboot properly

Tags: boot, dual-boot, filesystem

Actually I have dual booted with Windows and Ubuntu 14.04 and it's been almost 2 years. From the past few months when ever I reboot my PC ( from Ubuntu) Ubuntu is not able boot properly and every time it says cannot find folder '/' and when I use( Fsck ) command( using a live USB or from recovery mode) everything starts working fine.

Comment: SO what does `fsck` say is the problem?

Comment: It just asks fix error then I type  'y' and it continues . Haven't really read log

Comment: Look at `sudo journalctl --system | grep -i fsck`

Comment: It says journalctl command not found

Comment: Sorry what version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 lts

Comment: try `sudo dmesg -k | grep -i fsck`

Comment: It showed nothing